# Gulp babel({ presets: ["env"] }), não enxerga diretório externo

Tags: javascript, gulp, babel

Estou usando Gulp para compilar meus arquivos JS.
Tenho DUAS pastas onde existem arquivos JS, uma DENTRO do projeto (pasta filha `themes/`) e outra esta FORA (pasta pai `modules/`).

Ao usar o:

```js
babel({
  minified: true,
  presets: ["env"]
}))
```

os arquivos js de DENTRO do projeto (pasta `themes/`) compilam normalmente, mas os que estão FORA dão erro no `presets: ["env"]`.

```
Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "C:\\projetos\\...
```

Parece que o presets: ["env"] não consegue enxergar as pastas pai, no caso o que esta acima da pasta `themes/`.

**Obs 1**: O arquivo `gulpfile.js` que roda o `presets: ["env"]` esta dentro da pasta `themes/`.

**Obs 2**: Qualquer outra função do Gulp, como por exemplo copiar arquivos da pasta `modules/` para dentro da pasta `themes/` funciona normalmente, é apenas o `presets: ["env"]` que da o erro.

Estrutura das pastas:

```js
projetos/
  |-modules/
    |-js/file-module.js
  |-profile/
    |-contrib/
      |-themes/
        |-js/file-theme.js
      node_modules/
      gulpfile.js
```

Pergunta resumida:

Como faço para o `preset: ["env"]` que é executado de dentro do arquivo `gulpfile.js` enxergar o arquivo `modules/js/file-module.js` lembrando que o `gulpfile.js` esta dentro da pasta `themes/`?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver adicionando em presets o nome da pasta onde ele iria buscar o pacote e em seguida colocando o .map(require.resolve) para achar a pasta.

O código final ficou assim:

```js
.pipe(babel({
  presets: ['babel-preset-env'].map(require.resolve)
}))

// Também é possível adicionando o preset abaixo:

.pipe(babel({ 
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] 
}))
```